# Is buying alcohol considered jariyah sins?

Tags: sin, alcohol

Is buying alcohol considered jariyah sins (continues sins even if one die)? because if a person buying alcohol that means the person help the seller to buy more alcohol too, and if there is alcohol, another person will buy and drink it too.

So is the buyer before will get jariyah sins/sins continuously every time someone buys and drink from the seller before?

And if a person buying alcohol just for good like saints experiment also get jariyah sins too?
*Note: i ask this not because I want to buy, sell or drink alcohol. I am just curious, and sorry for my bad English.
Thank you ❤️

Comment: I only know about sadaqah jariyah (continuous). If there is some concept like continuous bad deeds you should present a proof of that first before asking whether something fits in a concept on which existence there's doubt.

Comment: Please provide any proofs of what you call "jariyah sins" because I haven't heard of any such thing in the Quran or the Hadith.

Answer (score 1):

**Asalaam Alaikum**

the term you have coined 'jariyah sins', i am not aware that it appears like that anywhere in hadith terminology or the quran. but the concept of being responsible for a sin instigated by you or caused by you is proven in islam. with main focus on the concept of your question, i will try to base my answer, insha Allah.

---

Allah azzawajjal said in quran ;

**And cooperate in righteousness and piety, but do not cooperate in sin and aggression. And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is severe in penalty.[5:2]**

with this verse it is very clear that we as muslims should not help in anything that is haram. the verse has a strong warning against such acts. so it's better that we don't have anything to do with alchohol.

specifically as you have mentioned buying alchohol, thats something we should not do as it is reported in a hadith ;

> It was narrated from Ibn ‘Umar that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
> “Wine is cursed from ten angles: The wine itself, the one who squeezes (the grapes etc), the one for whom it is squeezed, the one who sells it, the one who buys it, the one who carries it, the one to whom it is carried, the one who consumes its price, the one who drinks it and the one who pours it.” *(sunan ibn majah)*

---

regarding your concern of *jariyah sins*, the following hadith is the evidence for it.

> Narrated Ibn Jarir bin 'Abdullah:
> from his father that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Whoever starts a good tradition which is followed, then for him is a reward, and the likes of their rewards of whoever follows him, there being nothing diminished from their rewards. And whoever starts a bad tradition which is followed, then for him is the sin, and the likes of the sins of whoever follows him, there being nothing diminished from their sins." *(jami at-tirmidhi)*

*note : here bad tradition means sins and all types of such acts*

---

in conclusion the answer to your question is YES. if you support or help in anyway to make that haram business prosper then you will be held accountable.

---

may Allah the mighty and sublime grant us mercy and guide us to the straight path.

**ALLAH KNOWS BEST**

Comment: How about subscribing and watching movies on platform streaming service ? Like Netflix,amazon,etc. is it a jariyah sin too? How about if i buy halal things like candy in supermarket that sell alcohol?